# Indentation following a Zareba

Tags: typography

Is there an indentation following a section break that indicates a time lapse?  I know if you double-space in fiction to indicate a break in thought, there is no line indentation in the first line following. Is that also true with a bank of asterisks that indicate a temporal break?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127784/discussion-on-question-by-dr-l-bower-indentation-following-a-zareba).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question depends on the requirement of the publisher. You should indent after a temporal shift if the publisher requires you to indent each paragraph. Note that the Science Fiction & Fantasy Writers of America ([SFWA](https://www.sfwa.org/2005/01/04/manuscript-format/)) requires authors to indent each paragraph.

You don't have to indent after a temporal change if you are self-publishing or your publisher don't require indentation.